# FFMPEG - Filter volume has an unconnected output

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following FFMPEG command:

```
 ffmpeg -i ./master_video.mp4 -i ./temp/temp1.mp4 -i ./temp/temp2.mp4 -y -filter_complex [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,volume=0.1[aud1];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5/TB,fade=t=in:st=5:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=14:d=1:alpha=1[v1];[2:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,volume=0.1[aud2];[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB,fade=t=in:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=19:d=1:alpha=1[v2];[v0][v1]overlay=eof_action=pass[out1];[out1][v2]overlay=eof_action=pass[out2] -map [out2] -map [aud1][aud2] temp.mp4
```

But when I run it, I received the following error:

**error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Filter volume has an unconnected output**

Any ideas why that error is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to mix the audio outputs, it needs to be done within the filtergraph.

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i ./master_video.mp4 -i ./temp/temp1.mp4 -i ./temp/temp2.mp4 -filter_complex
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
 [1:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,volume=0.1[aud1];
 [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5/TB,fade=t=in:st=5:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=14:d=1:alpha=1[v1];
 [2:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,volume=0.1[aud2];
 [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB,fade=t=in:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=19:d=1:alpha=1[v2];
 [v0][v1]overlay=eof_action=pass[out1];
 [out1][v2]overlay=eof_action=pass[vout];
 [aud1][aud2]amix[aout]"
   -map [vout] -map [aout] temp.mp4
```

Note that any audio from the master video is ignored, as it would have been if your original command had worked. Also, the audio and video from the temp videos are no longer synchronized since the setpts expressions are different.